# Can I use bind variables with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have been trying to figure this out, but google wasn't turning up any real answers to my question.

I am using PHP (with CodeIgniter) and MySQL, is there a way that I can use bind variables with my SQL Statements?

Comment: I did...must have used wrong keywords...thanks for being a dick instead of being helpful though :)

Comment: Actually, I was helpful... I specifically linked you to the correct Google search terms (i.e. php mysql bind variables).  Thank _you_ for your effort to decrease the signal-to-noise ratio for mysql tagged questions here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, with CI you can:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ? AND email = ?";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($name,$email));

return $query->row_array();
```

This binds the $name and $email variable to th respective positions inside the query string. Is this what you mean?
There's also [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) (a custom ORM, or sortof), which is pretty nice.

All of the above automatically escape values. You can also escape manually with `$this->db->escape($string)` and, for column names, with `$this->db->protect_identifier($column_name)`. But it's all in the manual, have a read at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), which may be significantly faster than CIs functions, depending on the use case.